# Call a CTE based on a criterion - Case statement SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, case, common-table-expression

I have two CTEs with the same structure but reading data from two different tables.

Based on a date filter how do I call a CTE using an IF or CASE statement in SQL?

Something like this:

```
with combined_query as
(
 select * from CTE1 
 union all
 select * from CTE2
)
select 
case when date >= '2023-01-01' select * from CTE1
else select * from CTE2 end as criteria
from combined_query
```

The `date` column is in both CTEs.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain in details what the objective of your task is? Consider adding sample input tables, expected output, the DBMS tag to your post as well: these details contributes to get you relevant answers.

Comment: That's not how it would work. It's not clear why you would use a CTE or case _expression_ here anyway. Why not just `select * from table1 where date >= '2023-01-01' union all select * from table2 where date < '2023-01-01'`

Comment: a subselect can only return in your case a scalar value, so what exactly should be returend, post sample data and tables

Comment: Really you are thinking about SQL and relational data all wrong. We are working with sets in SQL and thinking about sets procedurally is going to lead you into brick walls. A CTE merely describes a set of data, it is not a procedural function that you can call conditionally. It is a set of data that will be created by the database based on your description through SQL. Once you describe it, in sql, it's going to exist when you submit your sql to the database. Going the union route as @Isolated suggests means you get back two sets of data that are unioned. One of them is always empty though.

Comment: Giving meaningless code is not a helpful way to say or clarify what you are trying to do, we don't know what you wish the language could do. [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using `WHERE` like this?

```
with combined_query AS (
    SELECT *, 'CTE1' AS source FROM CTE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'CTE2' AS source FROM CTE2
)
SELECT *
FROM combined_query
WHERE (date >= '2023-01-01' AND source = 'CTE1')
   OR (date < '2023-01-01' AND source = 'CTE2');
```